# Within each parent div, take an element located in a child div and append it to a different child div

Tags: jquery

I've got a few divs on a page which consist of product details; I need to take one of the product details (in this case the availability) located within div.availability and append it to the price container div (div.priceContainer).

```
<div class="standardItem">
<div class="additionalInfo">
<div class="availability">Available:34</div>
</div>
<div class="priceContainer">
</div>
</div>

<div class="standardItem">
<div class="additionalInfo">
<div class="availability">Available:56</div>
</div>
<div class="priceContainer">
</div>
</div>

<div class="standardItem">
<div class="additionalInfo">
<div class="availability">Available:21</div>
</div>
<div class="priceContainer">
</div>
</div>
```

and here is the jQuery code I've been fiddling with which kind of does what I need but produces unwanted results.

```
$(function() {
   $('div.standardItem div.availability').each(function() {
    $(this).appendTo('div.priceContainer');
   });
});
```

The results I'm getting is on the right track but it's taking the availability from every div and listing them all for each div instead of respectively. Basically every product div now has 3 availabilities.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: A working example of my issue can be seen here: https://codepen.io/fbarros/pen/EzWwvP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<sup>**The problem Is:**</sup> By using  `$(this).appendTo('div.priceContainer');` here you append the element to ALL of `priceContainer` elements .. so you just need to refer to the `priceContainer` element which is related to the `availability` element ..

Up to your HTML structure use `$(this).closest('div.standardItem').find('div.priceContainer');` instead of just `'div.priceContainer'`

```js
$(function() {
   $('div.standardItem div.availability').each(function() {
    $(this).appendTo($(this).closest('div.standardItem').find('div.priceContainer'));
   });
});
```

```css
.standardItem {
  width:100%; /* 40%; */
  background:#f1f1f1;
  padding:20px;
  margin: 0 0 10px 0;
  display:table;
}

.additionalInfo {
  float:left;
  background-color:#fff;
  padding:10px;
  width:30%;
  min-height:30px
}

.priceContainer {
  float:right;
  background-color:#1D7EC0;
  height:auto;
  min-height:30px;
  width:30%;
  color:#fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>

    <div class="standardItem">
      <div class="additionalInfo">
        <div class="availability">Available:34</div>
      </div>
      <div class="priceContainer"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="standardItem">
      <div class="additionalInfo">
        <div class="availability">Available:56</div>
      </div>
      <div class="priceContainer"></div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="standardItem">
      <div class="additionalInfo">
        <div class="availability">Available:21</div>
      </div>
      <div class="priceContainer"></div>
    </div>
    
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: ur Welcome @NewB .. Have a great day :-)